# Why slim.nets.vgg use conv2d instead of fully_connected layers?

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow/models/slim/nets, here is the link of relative snippets of [vgg](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/nets/vgg.py#L164-L174). I'am curious about why slim.nets.vgg use conv2d instead of fully_connected layers, although it works out the same way actually? Is it for the purpose of speed?
I appreciate some explanations. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is in the slim source " Note: All the fully_connected layers have been transformed to conv2d layers." and I was wondering why too...

Answer (score 1):

After a while, I think there is at least one reason that it can avoid weights converting mistakes.

Tensorflow/slim as well as other high-level libraries allows tensor formats either `BHWC`(batch_size, height, width, channel. Same below) by default or `BCHW`(for better performance).

When converting weights between these two formats, the weights `[in_channel, out_channel]` of first fc (fully connected layer, after conv layer) have to been reshaped to `[last_conv_channel, height, width, out_channel]` for example, then transposed to `[height, width, last_conv_channel, out_channel]` and reshaped again to `[in_channel, out_channel]`.

And if you use conv weights rather than fully connected weights, such transformation will explicitly applied on fc layer (conv weights actually). Surely will avoid converting mistakes.